# Jenkins Subversion plugin credentials error

Tags: svn, authentication, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have configured a Jenkins project to work with my Subversion repository, but after entering the proper credentials through the Jenkins interface (and successfully authenticate) the subversion plugin apparently is not finding the credentials.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Unable to access https://... : svn: E200015: OPTIONS ... failed 
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: OPTIONS
>   ... failed ... Caused by:
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: No credential
>   to try. Authentication failed ...

I looked on the Jenkins folder and the file **hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml** contains the credentials as expected.

The weird thing is I entered the credentials manually using TortoiseSVN, and those were saved on my AppData...\Subversion\auth\svn.simple, and after doing that Jenkins can connect to the repo. But I don't want to do that for every repository.
It seems to me that the Jenkins plugin is looking for the credentials at the svn folder instead of the Jenkins directory first.

I appreciate your comments and help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you experience same issues with v1.50 of subversion plugin? I had same issues after upgradinf from v1.43 to v1.44. After that had no bravrey to try again :(

Comment: The credential management of Subversion plugin is revamped in version 2.0+. You might want to try upgrading.

Comment: Still you have this error..??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910816/jenkins-subversion-plugin-credentials-error#comment43625069_15910816) above, the method that the Jenkins Subversion plugin uses to identify its associated credentials has been changed with version 2.0 and above.

Upgrade the plugin to the current version. Jenkins should then successfully connect to your various repositories without you having to manually enter them (via TortiseSVN).